# Javascript: data validation on array of objects

Tags: javascript, validation

I am running this task to teach my brother, he is asked to create a Javascript simple program to validate this data

```
[
    {code: ‘10001’, amount: ‘’},
    {code: ‘10002’, amount: ’50.00’},
    {code: ‘’, amount: ’60.00’},
    
]
```

I need to show the errors that if there is an amount, code shouldn't be empty.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some):

```js
const data = [
  {code: '1000', amount: ''},
  {code: '10002', amount: '50.00'},
  {code: '', amount: '60.00'},   
];

const isInValid = data.some(e => e.amount && !e.code);

console.log("Data is not valid?", isInValid);
```

Or use [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every):

```js
const data = [
  {code: '1000', amount: ''},
  {code: '10002', amount: '50.00'},
  {code: '', amount: '60.00'},   
];

const isValid = data.every(e => !e.amount || e.code);

console.log("Data is valid?", isValid);
```

Comment: Probably not correct. `e.code && e.amount` means *both code and amount are required". Maybe `!e.amount || e.code` ?

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky I think OP meant both are required

Comment: `!e.code || !e.amount` is exact reverse to `e.code && e.amount`. Second maybe correct in some meaning, but definitely not the first. With `some` still is not correct

Comment: @VasilyLiaskovsky thanks for highlighting the validation misunderstanding, feel free to suggest edits to the proposed solution

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @Majed Badawi, but with fixed validation expression.

```js
const data = [
  {code: '1000', amount: ''},       // is okay
  {code: '10002', amount: '50.00'}, // absolutely valid
  {code: '', amount: '60.00'},      // invalid
  {code: '', amount: ''},           // empty but still valid
];

const validFlags = data.map(e => !e.amount || e.code);
const isValid = validFlags.every(f => f);

console.log("Validation per record", validFlags.map(Boolean));
console.log("Final result", isValid);
```

Answer (score 0):

I mean if you is always getting an array of objs why not use Joi
You can define yow schemas and set the characteristics or needs of each prop on them objs
https://joi.dev/api/?v=17.3.0